# Identity Server 4 - Client web app errors on /signin-oidc

Tags: c#, identityserver4, openid-connect, asp.net-core-3.1

We have recently published two web apps each to an Azure App Service. An Identity Server 4 application and a .Net Core 3.1 web app, which is a client of the Identity Server. Running these locally through IIS/Visual Studio works fine and as they should. I can login into my client app through Identity Server and redirected back.

However, when publishing both projects to Azure I get the following error message.

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectMessage..ctor(string
> json)
>
> OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Failed to parse token response body as
> JSON. Status Code: 500. Content-Type: text/plain
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.RedeemAuthorizationCodeAsync(OpenIdConnectMessage
> tokenEndpointRequest)
>
> Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler.HandleRequestAsync()

I'll post the code of both the Identity Server and Client projects below. Any help on what the issue could be would be greatly appreciated.

**Identity.Startup:**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
        })
        .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });

        // Add Data GoCVContext
        string GoCVDataConnectionString = EnvironmentHandler.WebDB;
        services.AddDbContext<GoCVContext>(options => options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer(GoCVDataConnectionString));

        // Add Identity context
        string IdentityConnectionString = EnvironmentHandler.IdentityDB;
        var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

        services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(IdentityConnectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
        });

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            // password config
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;

            // lockout config
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;

            // sign in options
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;

            // add custom class for email tokens
            options.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = "CustomEmailConfirmation";
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddTokenProvider<CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>>("CustomEmailConfirmation");
        

        // set lifespan of all tokens used
        services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
        });
        // set life span for email confirmation token
        services.Configure<CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
        });

        var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;

            options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/Identity/Account/Login";
            options.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = "/Identity/Account/Logout";

            options.Authentication = new AuthenticationOptions()
            {
                CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromHours(10), // ID server cookie timeout set to 10 hours
                CookieSlidingExpiration = true
            };
        })
            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(IdentityConnectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            })
            .AddOperationalStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(IdentityConnectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
            })
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();

        services.AddLocalApiAuthentication();

        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
        .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
        {
            options.Authority = https://our_identity_server_url;

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });

        services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();

        // not recommended for production - you need to store your key material somewhere secure
        builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
        InitializeDatabase(app);

        var forwardOptions = new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto,
            RequireHeaderSymmetry = false
        };

        app.UseForwardedHeaders(forwardOptions);

        if (Environment.IsDevelopment() || Environment.IsProduction())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        // uncomment if you want to add MVC
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseIdentityServer();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "areas",
            template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");

            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

**Client config:**

```
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "Our client Id",
                    ClientName = "Our client name",
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("oursecret".Sha256()) },

                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.CodeAndClientCredentials,

                    AllowedCorsOrigins =
                    {
                        "https://our_client_app_url"
                    },

                    RedirectUris = { "https://our_client_app_url/signin-oidc" },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://our_client_app_url/signout-callback-oidc" },

                    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                        JwtClaimTypes.Role
                    }
                }
```

**Client web app .Startup**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            EnvironmentHandler.Init(_configuration, environment);
            
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();

            services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
            services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.Configure<RazorPagesOptions>
                (options => options.RootDirectory = "/Views/Home");

            string dbConnectionString = EnvironmentHandler.WebDB;
            services.AddDbContext<GoCVContext>(options => options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer(dbConnectionString));

            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://our_identity_server_url";
                options.ClientId = "our client Id";
                options.ClientSecret = "our secret";
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.SaveTokens = true;

                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                options.Scope.Add("profile");

                options.Scope.Add("roles");
                options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("role", "role");
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    RoleClaimType = "role"
                };
            });

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<GoCVContext>();
                context.Database.Migrate();
            }

            app.UseForwardedHeaders();

            if (env.IsDevelopment() || env.IsProduction())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Views/Shared/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                name: "areas",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```